# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis IN DBeaver while setting NOT NULL DEFAULT

Tags: oracle, dbeaver

when i am executing query in dbeaver I am getting missing right code paranthesis error

```
CREATE TABLE PersonsNotNull
(
P_Id int NOT NULL,
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'KHATTAR',
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255)
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the clauses the wrong way; the default value has to come before the null/not null indicator:

```
CREATE TABLE PersonsNotNull
(
P_Id int NOT NULL,
LastName varchar(255) DEFAULT 'KHATTAR' NOT NULL ,
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255)
);

Table PERSONSNOTNULL created.
```

You're creating a [relation table](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_7002.htm#i2149006) so the [relation properties](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_7002.htm#i2146032) and [column properties](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_7002.htm#CEGEDHJE) syntax apply:

[image: column properties]

From that you can see that the optional `DEFAULT expr` clause comes before the [constraints](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/clauses002.htm#CJAEDFIB), which includes null/not null:

[image]